# Health/Energy consumption and restoration

Tags: android, game-engine

I am new to developing games and apps in android, as much a noob as i am i was wondering how i could implement a health/energy bar.
Such as candy crush, so when you die you lose 1 health and a timer starts for aprox 15 minutes and when that timer ends you recive that 1 health back.
If you lose 5 times you run out of health and cannot play until you have restored atleast 1 health.

I was thinking of tracking it like a score system, so when you press the play button 1 health is removed and you start a timer, not sure how i would implement this thou.

Any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Pretty sure there are tutorials you could find with Google.

Comment: There most probly is a tutorial, but i cant find any :/

Answer (score 1):

*Theoretical attempt, implementation up to you.*

I would have a SQLite DB where you store your lifes. Initially let's say 5. When a users fails it is substracted. Now this is where you would add or change an entry in a DB or in SharedPrefs.
Your DB would look like:

```
lifes=>4
restoreTime=>27.02.2014 14:34:22 (that is the time when a new life will be added)
```

In you game loop just periodically check for if you are already behind that time. If so add lifes by calculating the difference of time divided by the length of your "regen" time and

1. if(newLifes == 5) delete restore time or set it to infinity or a date in 9999 years or so (so it wont increment in the next gameloop check).
2. else update restore time to the next time it will add lifes.

You see: Making games is not that trivial ...